# Read variable value from group_vars in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to read the variable value from group vars. But ansible is not able to find the value.

My inventory folder is like:

```
prod.ini
uat1.ini
uat2.ini
```

my uat1.ini looks like:

```
[server a]
12.12.12.12

[server b]
13.13.131.1
```

my uat2.ini looks like:

```
[server a]
1.1.1.2

[server b]
2.23.12.5
```

group vars folder looks like:

```
 all
 environment
```

inside environment  folder i have sub folders which are

```
uat1 and uat2
```

in uat1 and uat2 i have file named pick.yml

for uat1 i have below pick.yml

```
modern: "re run"
```

for uat2 i have below pick.yml

```
modern: "no re run"
```

my playbook looks like:

```
- name: try and run to get the value of group vars
  hosts: server a
  debug:
     var: modern
```

i run my playbook using below command:

```
 ansible-playbook -i inventory/uat2.ini  -b playbookname
```

my expectation is - that it should return the value from uat2 which is "no re run". but is not not able to return that. 
But when i put that group vars in group_vars/all, playbook is able to read it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your hierarchy is correct:
Ansible will automatically load variables from group_vars (default path is /etc/ansible/group_vars).

In your case, there are 3 groups: `all`, `server a` and `server b`.

Assuming there's a host in group `server a` called "server_a", the following group_vars will be loaded for this host (by default, only if these files exist):

```
/etc/ansible/group_vars/all.yml
/etc/ansible/group_vars/<group name>.yml
{{ playbook_dir }}/group_vars/all.yml
{{ playbook_dir }}/group_vars/<group name>.yml
```

So unless you create the correct hierarchy, or adjust the path of group_vars in your config file or playbook, you will not be able to import group_vars.

example hierarchy for your use case:

```
/etc/ansible/group_vars:
    all.yml
    server a.yml
    server b.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables:

> Ansible loads host and group variable files by searching paths relative to the inventory file or the playbook file. If your inventory file at /etc/ansible/hosts contains a host named ‘foosball’ that belongs to two groups, ‘raleigh’ and ‘webservers’, that host will use variables in YAML files at the following locations:

```
/etc/ansible/group_vars/raleigh # can optionally end in '.yml', '.yaml', or '.json'
/etc/ansible/group_vars/webservers
/etc/ansible/host_vars/foosball
```

> You can also create directories named after your groups or hosts. Ansible will read all the files in these directories in lexicographical order. An example with the ‘raleigh’ group:

```
/etc/ansible/group_vars/raleigh/db_settings
/etc/ansible/group_vars/raleigh/cluster_settings
```

In your case the `environment` folder is the group name. Since you have no `environment` group it is not used. Furthermore, the groups named `uat1` and `uat2` do not exist as inventories are not groups.

The `all` group variables work because it is a special default group:

> There are two default groups: all and ungrouped. The all group contains every host.

It sounds like you want to have a set of variables per-inventory. What you could do in this case is set the variables in the inventory for the `all` group:

```
[all:vars]
modern="re run"

[server a]
12.12.12.12

[server b]
13.13.131.1
```

Which would apply the `modern` var to all hosts in that specific inventory.

Alternatively, if you are already using the two inventories more like groups, you might consider arranging your hosts into a single inventory and creating a `uat1` and `uat2` group such as:

```
[server a]
12.12.12.12
1.1.1.2

[server b]
13.13.131.1
2.23.12.5

[uat1]
12.12.12.12
13.13.131.1

[uat2]
1.1.1.2
2.23.12.5
```

In which case you could then have `group_vars/uat1` and `group_vars/uat2` files.

These two ideas should hopefully give you a better picture of how to use groups and group variables.

Comment: in my inventory file:  

    [all:vars]
     environment = uat2

    [server a]
    12.12.12.12

   [ server b]
   13.13.131.1
   
this should work, right? But its not working.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. That sets the variable `environment` to `uat1`. It doesn't have anything to do with choosing the `group_vars` folder.